# Get input inside same <td>

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get previous input inside the same ?

I have the following table:

```
start-loop
    <td>...</td>
    <td>...</td>
    <td align=center>
            <input type="hidden" id="ContactPW" name="ContactPW" value="#UserPW#" />
            <input type="hidden" id="ContactEmail" name="ContactEmail" value="#UserEmail#" />
            <input type="hidden" id="ContacName" name="ContactName" value="#UserName#" />
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="test();" value="Login" />
    </td>
end- loop
```

I would like to get in my test() function the values for "ContactPW", "ContactEmail", and "ContactName", but using $("#ContactPW").val() I just get the first item in the loop, not the row that I click the button.

Does anyone know how I can do it?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on question and clarify. Is the code intended to capture all values of children between <td> tags (including the <td>...</td>)?

Comment: Which back end are you using? is the `start-loop` in html?

Comment: ColdFusion... <cfloop>. I'm looking to do it with JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your test function, you can use jquery `.parent().find()` which means, your btn elem will look for parent and find the child with the name that you define. function as sample below,

html

```
<input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="test(this);" value="Login" />
```

javascript

```
function test(e){
   $(e).parent().find("[name='ContactPW']").val();
}
```